# Why is my object.children undefined?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, railscasts

I'm running javascript on Ruby on Rails to insert a form dynamically into a page when the user clicks on a link.

It's not working, but one particular bug gets my goat: that my form return form.children UNDEFINED in the debugging console.

Here is the form (in Rails):

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name, 'Tag:' %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>   
</div>
```

And here is the javascript in application.js;

```
function add_fields(link, association, form) {
console.log(form);
console.log(form.children);
link.insertBefore(form, link.previousSibling.previousSibling);
}
```

I have tested whether the app actually calls the javascript by outputting text and the like and it works. The problem is clearly with my form.

Finally, the console output:

```
<div class="field">
<label for="post_tags_attributes_4_name">Tag:</label>
<input id="post_tags_attributes_4_name" name="post[tags_attributes][4][name]" size="30" type="text" />  
</div> application.js:21
undefined application.js:22
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

By the way, I'm trying to implement railscast #197 on dynamically inserted nested forms and it's been a disaster!

--EDIT---

Here is how I call the add_fields function that builds the field element:

The ruby function:

```
module TagsHelper
    def link_to_add_fields(name, post_form, association)
        new_object = post_form.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
        tag_field = post_form.fields_for :tags, new_object do|tag_form|
            render("tag_field", :f=>tag_form)
        end
        #debugger
        link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(tag_field)}\")")
    end
end
```

And here is the tag_field html:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, 'Tag:' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>   
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like `form` is not a DOM element. Could you please show us how you invoke the `add_fields` function (with which values)?

Comment: Do you mean `childNodes` instead of `children`?

Comment: Maybe your test browser doesn't support [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children)

Comment: *" my form (which is a div)"* Huh? Which is it? A form, or a div?

Comment: @Bergi: just updated my response with more details on the values add_field invokes.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly this won't work because an element can't have a child that is also a sibling.

```
link.insertBefore(form, link.previousSibling.previousSibling);
```

Your code want's to put `form` as a child of `link` *and* before one of `link`'s siblings, which would be impossible.

Remember, [`.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) must be called from the *parent* that it's being inserted into. So to insert `form` before `link`, the `.insertBefore` must be called from the parent of `link`.

---

So maybe you meant to use `link.parentNode` instead.

```
link.parentNode.insertBefore(form, link.previousSibling.previousSibling);
```

This will insert `form` before the second previous sibling of `link`.

Comment: y  While your input is useful it doesn't explain why Javascript doesn't recognize my div at all. For instance, if I build a simple div with label and text field, then pass it to the insertBefore, it gets inserted (in the corrected scenario you submitted). However, the div I pass into the function does not. Can I be honest with you? I find it frustrating.

Comment: @Laurent: `form` is a string of HTML? `console.log(typeof form)` You'll have better luck when asking JavaScript questions if you provided the rendered HTML instead of server-side application code.

Comment: I figured it out. I was passing the form (as you can see) and a link, and trying to place the form before the link. I wasn't escaping javascript before. But when I typed $(link) instead, the tag was properly placed. If anyone has a really simple explanation of what the difference between link and $(link) was, and wants to share it, I'd be delighted.

Comment: @Laurent: To be honest, I can't see that you're passing the `form`. All I see is that you're passing `\"#{escape_javascript(tag_field)}\"`, and I don't know what your server renders with that syntax. If it renders a selector string like `"#my_form"`, then you're *not* passing the form. You're passing a selector string *(think CSS)* that hopefully points to your form. So `form` would be that string, and `$(form)` would be passing that string to the `$` function, which I'll assume refers to the `jQuery` library. If it is jQuery, it'll perform a DOM selection using that selector.

Comment: ...now in your case `link` is being passed `this`, which is presumably the element that received the event. When you do `$(this)`, you're creating a new jQuery object *(again assuming jQuery)* with that element, which would change the meaning of `.insertBefore` because it would be using jQuery's `insertBefore` instead of the native DOM `.insertBefore`. So basically it sounds like you need to do some basic tutorials that cover native DOM methods, and then usage of the jQuery library.

Comment: That was the problem so if you want to accrue approvals copy/paste as separate answer and I'd be happy to oblige